# how to retrieve favourite list using twitter-api?

Tags: twitter

how can i obtains a complete list of user that have "favourite" a tweet using twitter's api?

i have googled and found something about an undocumented api "activity/summary.json"  ... there adr other "ufficial" ways?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API doesn't support the sort of request you're looking for, and it's easy to see why.  A list of UserIds that marked a particular tweet as a "favorite" could number in the tens of millions.